# jQuery focus on live input field

Tags: jquery, focus, live

I've got a couple of input fields (generated by a framework). When the user confirms the input on the first input field the focus should move to the second field.
I've coded something like this:

```
$(matnrId).live("load", function() {
  $(matnrId).focus();
});

$(matnrId).live("click", function() {
  if ($(matnrId).val() === "Enter Description") {
    $(matnrId).val('').css('color', '#000');
    $(matnrId).die("click");
  }
});

$(matnrId).live("focusout", function() {
  if ($(matnrId).val() === '') {
    $(matnrId)
      .val("Enter Description")
      .css('color', '#999');
    $(matnrId).live("click", function() {
      $(matnrId).val('').css('color', '#000');
    });

  }
});
```

When I click on field named `matnr` the text "Enter Description" disappears (which is what I wanted). When I move the focus out it appears again if the user did not input any text.
The only thing that is not working is the `focus()`thingy. I think it's because of this field is regenerated by the framework and I should be using some `.live()` trick. 
But I don't know what to do.
Any clue.

Comment: Live is deprecated as of jquery 1.7. Use .on instead

Comment: re: "the focus() thingy" -- is it not focusing the field? Or is it focusing, but not behaving how you want afterwards?

Comment: I knew that. However, if I replace `live` with `on` the click/blur thingy won't work. Don't know why.

Comment: It's not focusing on the field at all. I think that the reason is quite simple. The DOM objects are modified by the rendering engine afterwards, as I said this is coded within a framework and I should attach this focus to some `live`event. I need a statement which says: set the focus on this DOM element, now and in the future. I think that the jQuery statement `$(elem).focus()`works only with the DOM elements that match the selector now, but not in the future. Any help?